# CircularprogressIndicator while loading the home screen during logging in app in flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, future, flutter-circularprogressindicator

I was looking to show circularprogressindicator while user is being logged into device.I saw various methods online one of them was by using bool _isloading like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59507960/async-await-to-do-circularprogressindicator-in-a-login-page-in-flutter) but here it replaced my button with curcularprogressindicator and not logged in too + I want the indicator in center of screen and other was while using futurebuilder which i don't require. So, i thinked a lot and couldn't find anything ,so if you can help me it will be very greatful.

My code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:green_earth/mainpage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> attemptSignUp(String username, String password,BuildContext context) async {
  final http.Response res = await http.post(
          'https://green-earth.herokuapp.com/signup',
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body:jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "email":username,
        "password":password
      }),
  );
  CircularProgressIndicator();
  if (res.statusCode==200){
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
  }
  else{
    _showMyDialog(context,res.statusCode);
  }
}
// print("res status code=${res.statusCode}  $username $password ${jsonDecode(res.body)}")
Future<void> _showMyDialog(BuildContext context,int statuscode) async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Error'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              statuscode==422?Text('Email ID is already taken. Please try again!'):Text('Authorisation was failed with status code $statuscode'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

calling function

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap:(){
                      if(formkey2.currentState.validate()==true){
                        signupUsername=signupUsernameController.text;
                        signupPassword=signupPasswordController.text;
                        attemptSignUp(signupUsername, signupPassword,context);

                      }
                    },
                    child: PrimaryButton(
                      btnText: "Create Account",
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: You can use `snakbar` instead of `CircularProgressBar`

Comment: No, I want circularprogressindicator only

Comment: Where is your widget tree?

Comment: Why u need widget tree , i am just calling attemptsignup function on button click there ,that widget tree is vey long and has 2 different dart files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer the person provided in the other question, if you don't want the button to be replaced you could use the same logic, but use a [stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) instead.

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    (... your login form ...),
    _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : SizedBox.srink(),
  ],
);
```

You can modify it to any style you want (if you also want to blurr the bg, etc) but that is the basic approach.

**Update**

Change your on tap to something like this:

```
onTap:() async {
  if(formkey2.currentState.validate()==true){
    signupUsername=signupUsernameController.text;
    signupPassword=signupPasswordController.text;
    setState((){
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    await attemptSignUp(signupUsername, signupPassword,context);
    setState((){
      _isLoading = false;
    }); 
}
```

Noticed I've made `onTap` async to wait for the future, and also I'm using `setState` to simplify the example, but it means to update the UI.

Comment: I have edited the calling function, now where acc. to u i can use this

Comment: I exactly did this and my button was replaced with indicator ,also u didn't include your Sizedbox.shrink anywhere here?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot be any more clearer. `SizedBox.shrink()` is in the ternary operation if the _isLoading is false. You REMOVE the operation from your button. Your button should not have the `_isLoading ? ...` logic.